# Subscription doesn't appear although success is reported

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to create a subscription for attributes of an existing entity in OrionCB.

URL
http://130.206.80.120:1026/NGSI10/subscribeContext

Method
POST

Headers
Content-Type: application/xml

Body

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<subscribeContextRequest>
  <entityIdList>
    <entityId type="finesce_meteo" isPattern="false">
      <id>finesce_meteo</id>
    </entityId>
  </entityIdList>
  <attributeList>
    <attribute>precip</attribute>
  </attributeList>
  <reference>http://localhost:5050/notify</reference>
  <duration>P100Y</duration>
  <notifyConditions>
    <notifyCondition>
      <type>ONCHANGE</type>
      <condValueList>
        <condValue>precip</condValue>
      </condValueList>
    </notifyCondition>
  </notifyConditions>
  <throttling>PT5S</throttling>
</subscribeContextRequest>
```

This operation retrieves 200 OK headers code, with this body:

```
<subscribeContextResponse>
  <subscribeResponse>
    <subscriptionId>54c5f049286043784451d08b</subscriptionId>
    <duration>P100Y</duration>
    <throttling>PT5S</throttling>
  </subscribeResponse>
</subscribeContextResponse>
```

The problem is when I'm trying to check if it's created. When I'm trying to list subscriptions, it doesn't appears. I'm using this line:

```
echo 'db.csubs.find().pretty()' | mongo orion
```

But if I delete this subscription with unsubscribeContextRequest, I get 200 OK code. It suggests this subscription exists.

The fact a subscription exists (because it's created and deleted ok), and not appears any moment when i listing subscriptions, is rare.

Please, is there something wrong?

I'm trying this whit cygnus proccess started, and the same process with cygnus stopped, obtaining the same result.

Regards

Comment: Please edit your question to show the command line which started Orion Context Broker, typically the result of the  `ps ax | grep contextBroker` command.

Comment: [root@orioncb ~]# ps ax | grep contextBroker
 6889 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep contextBroker
28707 ?        Ssl  672:56 /usr/bin/contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost localhost -db orion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo `find()` command returns the first 20 results matching the query, thus if you have more subscriptions than that (e.g. more than 30) it may happen that the particular one you are searching for is not retrieved. (With mongo interactive shell you can get the next batch of 20 result using the `it` command, but not sure how this work when mongo runs in non-interactive mode).

Thus, I'd recommend you include the id you are searching for in the query. For example, if the id you get in the Orion request is "54c90821286043500575eecf" then you could use:

```
echo 'db.csubs.find({_id: ObjectId("54c90821286043500575eecf")}).pretty()' | mongo orion
```

Morevoer, as you are expecting just one result, you can use `findOne()` and save the usage of `pretty()`, i.e.:

```
echo 'db.csubs.findOne({_id: ObjectId("54c90821286043500575eecf")})' | mongo orion
```